# mysql query with either OR and right join on result of either or

Tags: mysql, join

I'm writing an internal/private messaging/email system for a new site and so far its been going very nicely but I just hit a snag... the trash folder.

I need to do a query that includes all records where fields (a AND b) = one setting OR (x AND y) = another setting and then right join that record on the user table so that I can tell who originated the record/message.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT * FROM mail AS M
RIGHT JOIN users AS U on U.userid = M.frm_userid or M.to_userid /* result of WHERE */
WHERE (frm_userid='$userid' AND frm_status=3) OR (to_userid='$userid' AND to_status=3) 
ORDER BY some_date_field DESC
```

I'm stuck on the RIGHT JOIN ON U.userid = I have no clue! I'm sure there's a way to do this but I just don't know MYSQL quite well enough to pull this one off!

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the TO and FROM processing into different parts of a UNION:

```
SELECT M.to_userid FROM mail AS M
JOIN users AS U on U.userid = M.frm_userid and M.frm_status=3
WHERE M.frm_userid = '$userid'
UNION
SELECT M.frm_userid FROM mail as M
JOIN users AS U on U.userid = M.to_userid and M.to_status=3
WHERE M.to_userid = '$userid'
ORDER BY some_date_field DESC
```

Comment: I had thought about/tried the IN statement and the problem is it returns the same record twice.

Comment: I updated the query to use a UNION - I think that will remove the duplicate and will probably perform better.  "OR" expressions typically are slow.

Comment: That works well BUT I think I need to reverse them so that to_userid is first... I want to display the senders name if not "me" and the recipients name if not "me"  frm_user="me" if I'm sending, to_user="me" if you're sending. Make sense?

Comment: I went with your original solution and edited the code to reflect that as it works and I just brutforced through the rest... it got me there at 5:50a this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT 
         * 
    FROM 
         mail AS M
    RIGHT JOIN 
         users AS U on (U.userid = M.frm_userid or U.userid = M.to_userid)
    WHERE 
         (frm_userid='$userid' AND frm_status=3) OR (to_userid='$userid' AND to_status=3) 
    ORDER BY 
         some_date_field DESC
```